# How to create a hit counter for each published node to find out how often a specific node has been viewed?

Tags: nodes

I’m trying to create a hit counter for each published node. I’ve been googling this feature for Drupal 6.x and tried a few hits but with no luck.

I’ve enabled the Statistics module for my site and under admin/reports/settings I’ve enabled the counter but can’t seem to figure out how to put a hit counter on each overview page and node page.

I found a post explaining that I could use a customize query as such `SELECT count(*) from accesslog where node = node` but when I navigate to my database, the access log is empty (don’t know if it require to some time to enable the page / hit counter).

I want to count every hit and not only unique hits so each time a person access a node it should “just” increment a visitor number and I want to show it within my node-templates (not block) for some specific node content types.

I might miss something but any help or suggestions would really be appreciated.

Comment: What theme are you using? This should come out of the box. If you don't see the number of hits, switch to garland theme and check whether it's there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a settings page at `admin/reports/settings`, try looking there first.

Also, look in the `node_counter` table instead of `accesslog`.  The query should actually be as follows ($nid being the node ID of the node which you want records for).:

```
SELECT totalcount FROM {node_counter} WHERE nid = $nid;
```

On another note, I'm pretty sure if you enable the Statistics module, you can simply pull the node's page view count out in [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted, thank you so very much!

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/151205/18099 for using statistics_() own functions. If you would like to avoid the db yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if not doing sql's yourself and instead relying on the module putting in the links in your pages, after turning on the settings mentioned above, be aware of the permission `view post access counter` so users less than admins can see the information as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module might be a valid alternative to consider? Refer to its [community docu](https://www.drupal.org/node/2432339) for some more details.

**Be aware**: I'm the new maintainer of this module, it was [unsupported until recently](https://www.drupal.org/node/2380441) ...