# How to count the number of unique views of a node?

Tags: nodes

Is there any possible way to find the number of views of a node.

For example:

I have created a node called "Sample".

**If i viewed it once then the count should be increased as 1 view and when i view the same node again it should not get increased.**

Is there any module to do that..

Else what's the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how much traffic you site has and how big your server is. If you need to create a view count like this, it will require that you disable page cache making your site slower and demanding more resources from your server, or run expensive queries on every node view.

You could do this with Drupal, but there isn't a module that provides this functionality for you. The statistics module will count all views of the node. To implement this you would need to use either `hook_node_view` or `hook_boot` and write to a database the nid of the node being used and a token for the user. If you don't want to count anonymous users, you can use the uid, else you would have to use a combination of uid and session id to try not to count the same anonymous users twice.

A better way if you have a lot of traffic is to use an external tool like Google Analytics and then draw data from there.

Both solutions will require custom code though.

Comment: Doesn't the core statistics module contain the ability to count page views out of the box?

I agree Google Analytics is a better option though, Statistics can fill a database pretty damn quickly on larger sites.  The Google Analytics API would also allow pulling page views into Drupal based on the path, which is nice :-)

Comment: @Chapabu The core statistics module doesn't allow to count unique views, which is what OP asked for.

Comment: Aaah, apologies!  I misunderstood/misread.

Comment: There are a few contrib modules that extend the core statistics counter to be more considerate of 'unique' visitors. (like statistics_advanced)

Answer (score 2):

Enable **statistics** module in your site and then go to configuration of statistics module which is at

--> admin/config/system/statistics.

--> CONTENT VIEWING COUNTER SETTINGS check "Count content views".

Then go to any node like node/1 or node/2,
at bottom see the number of reads like "1 read" / "50 reads"
you can also find the number of **node views in any View** go to -> add fields and search --> " **Content statistics: Total views**"
This will bring node views to your content.

Comment: This module is great but it counts **every** view, not just unique views...

Answer (score 1):

There indeed indeed appears to be contrib module that provides *unique* page visits for an entity.  I haven't used it yet but just came across it when search for this https://www.drupal.org/project/piwik_stats.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 6 you can use "[Statistics Advanced](http://drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced)" module that allows to track only unique visitors.

For Drupal 7 this module has unstable version http://drupal.org/node/816040

Answer (score 0):

Statistics module has a short API for doing this job

```
$nodevisit=statistics_get($node->nid);
print $nodevisit['totalcount'];
print $nodevisit['daycount'];
```